# fread of data isn't equal to fwrite of that same data

Tags: arrays, c, char, fwrite, fread

```
int main(){
    char * saveMe = "123 ABC";
    int len = strlen(saveMe);
    int charSize = sizeof(char);
    char * loadMe = malloc(len+1);

    FILE * fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    fwrite(saveMe, charSize, len, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    fread(loadMe, charSize, len, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    printf((strcmp(saveMe, loadMe)) ? "Strings are the Same.\n" : "Strings are different.\n");

    free(loadMe);
    return 0;
}
```

If I save the string and then reload it, "Strings are different".

I'm sure it's something simple, but I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: We don't compare strings using the `==` operator in C, instead use `strcmp`. Also, you don't have room for the trailing NUL, you want `malloc(len + 1);` and `fwriite(..., ..., len + 1, ...`

Comment: Thanks David. Even with those changes, no dice.

Comment: Well, now you need `!strcmp` or `(strcmp(...) == 0)`,  keep in mind that `strcmp` returns 0 if both strings are equal.

Comment: That's it. Thank you. Now back to figuring out why it doesn't work when I'm encrypting / decrypting stuff.

Comment: loadMe is'nt NULL terminated. Try using calloc()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two mistakes here.

1. `fopen("test.txt", "w");` should be `..., "wb"` or `..., "rb"` for all calls to `fopen` that will be used with `fread()` or `fwrite()`. I suspect your platform is Windows and it's mauling your ciphertext because of this mistake.
2. `(strcmp(saveMe, loadMe)) ? same : different` but `strcmp` returns 0 for identical.

Can't tell if you have this coming or not because of reduction; but you can't use `strcmp()` on ciphertext because of the tendency of embedded nulls; you have to keep track in another variable yourself.

Comment: The issue was wb and rb for the ciphertext. The strcmp error was just me trying to simplify the code and messing it up. I'm using Ubuntu, but always happy to blame windows anyway!